# Metric Derived From Differential on Hyperbolic Plane

Tags: differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I'm reading Katok's Fuchsian Groups, and I'm confused on how the metric on the unit disk model is derived from the differential $$ds = \frac{2|dz|}{1-|z|^2}.$$

To be more specific, we first have the upper half-plane given by $\mathcal{H} = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: \text{Im}(z) > 0\}$ with the differential given by
$$ds = \frac{\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}}{y}$$
where $z = x + iy$. Using the differential, we can define a metric $\rho$ on $\mathcal{H}$ by taking the infimum of the lengths of paths between two given points. We also have the unit disk model $\mathcal{U} = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| < 1\}$. The transformation
$$f(z) = \frac{zi+1}{z+i}$$
is a 1-1 map of $\mathcal{H}$ onto $\mathcal{U}$. This map induces on a metric $\rho^*$ on $\mathcal{U}$ by
$$\rho^*(z,w) = \rho(f^{-1}(z), f^{-1}(w)).$$
My confusion is when Katok says that because the following identity holds for $f$,
$$\frac{2|f'(z)|}{1-|f(z)|^2} = \frac{1}{\text{Im}(z)}, $$
then $\rho^*$ can be identified with the metric derived from the differential
$$ds = \frac{2|dz|}{1-|z|^2}.$$
I see the obvious resemblance between these expressions, but I don't know how to formally connect them. How do I use that identity on $f$ to show that the metric derived from that differential coincides with the metric $\rho^*$.

Edit: Fixed the denominator of the differential on the upper half-plane.

Comment: You're running into problems because the definition for your original metric is incorrect. It should be $$ds = \frac{\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}}{y}$$ Now it matches up with the RHS of the identity with $\frac{1}{y}$

Comment: @NinadMunshi Sorry that was a typo on my part. I see that it matches with the identity, but I'm still confused how to rigorously connect the identity with the metric derived from the differential.

Comment: You have to compute $f^*dz$ and then $f^*|dz|$ and $f^*(1-|z|^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to see the proof by using the following notation instead

$$f(z) \equiv z_{\mathcal{U}}(z_{\mathcal{H}})$$

where $z_S$ denotes which set the $z$'s lie in. From here we can see that

$$\frac{2\left|\frac{dz_{\mathcal{U}}}{dz_{\mathcal{H}}}\right|}{1-|z_{\mathcal{U}}|^2} = \frac{1}{\operatorname{Im}(z_{\mathcal{H}})} \implies \frac{2\left|dz_{\mathcal{U}}\right|}{1-|z_{\mathcal{U}}|^2} = \frac{|dz_{\mathcal{H}}|}{\operatorname{Im}(z_{\mathcal{H}})} \equiv ds$$

by the chain rule.